# The fastest algorithm to find the largest span (i,j) such that , ai + ai+1 +....+aj = bi + bi+1 +....+bj in arrays a and b

Tags: arrays, asymptotic-complexity, array-algorithms

I encountered this problem while preparing for my exams.

Given two arrays of numbers a1,..., an and b1,....,bn where each number is 0 or 1, the fastest algorithm to find the largest span (i,j) such that , ai + ai+1 +....+aj = bi + bi+1 +....+bj or report that there is not such span.

(A) Takes O(3^n) and  omega(2^n) time if hashing is permitted.

(B) Takes O(n^3) and  omega(n^2.5) and time in the key comparison mode

(C)Takes  theta(n) time and space

(D)Takes O(square-root(n)) time only if the sum of 2n elements is an even number.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2006-question-54/

Comment: https://gateoverflow.in/1832/gate-cse-2006-question-54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can think of has O(n^2) and omega(n) time if anybody bothers to do the right check. It could probably be improved if anybody manages to find a way to take advantage of all values being 0 and 1.

```
int[] a = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
int[] b = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 };

int lastSum = 0; int lastI = 0; int lastJ = 0;
int sumA = 0; int sumB = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) // start the sum at [i].
{
    sumA = a[i]; sumB = b[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++) // summing ends on [j]
    //do
    {
        if (sumA == sumB && (lastJ - lastI < j - i))
        {
            lastSum = sumA;
            lastI = i; lastJ = j;
            if (j == a.Length - 1) // you will never find a bigger interval.
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("(i, j) = (" + lastI + ", " + lastJ + ")");
                return;
            }
        }
        sumA += a[j];
        sumB += b[j];
    }
}
Console.Out.WriteLine("(i, j) = (" + lastI + ", " + lastJ + ")");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an O(n) algorithm,

```
l=[1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
m=[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
delta=[]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    delta.append(l[i]-m[i])

leftsum=[0]
for i in range(1,len(l)+1):
    leftsum.append(leftsum[i-1]+delta[i-1])

sumHash=[-1]*len(l)

maxLen=0;
leftIndex=-1
rightIndex=-1

for i in range(0,len(l)+1):
    if sumHash[leftsum[i]]!=-1:
        if maxLen<i-sumHash[leftsum[i]]:
            maxLen=i-sumHash[leftsum[i]]
            leftIndex=sumHash[leftsum[i]]
            rightIndex=i-1
    else:
        sumHash[leftsum[i]]=i

print 'len=',maxLen,'left=',leftIndex,'right=',rightIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in θ(n) time and space.

1. since there are total n elements, the maximum sum is n
   for both arrays.
2. difference in sum varies from -n to n. So there are a total of 2n+1 possible values.
3. If the difference between two prefix sums of 2 arrays becomes the same at two points, then subarrays between 2 points have the same sum.

algorithm:

1. create an auxiliary array of size 2n+1 to store the starting points of all possible values of differences.
2. Initialize starting of all differences as -1.
3. maxlen = 0;presum1=0;presum2=0;(prefix sum of 2 arrays)
4. for( int i=0;i>n;i++){

   1. preSum1 += arr1[i], preSum2 += arr2[i];
   2. curr_diff = preSum1 - PreSum2;
   3. diffIndex = n + curr_diff {curr_diff(-n to n)
   4. if curr_diff is 0 , maxlen = i+1;
   5. Else if curr_diff is seen the first time, starting
      point of curr_diff is -1, update starting point as i
   6. Else, then consider i as the endpoint and the final length of the current same sum span. if the length is more then update maxlen
5. return maxlen